# MySQL eav велосипед и как хранить десятичные числа

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, eav

всем акулам MySQL и вообще всего IT.

Моя неграмотность технической части строения баз данных, в т.ч. mysql породила такой вопрос, при создании велосипеда EAV модели в моем проекте, как лучше (правильнее) хранить десятичные числа.

У меня вот такой велосипед: [image: велосипед EAV]

Коротко:

- eav_ent - хранилище сущностей
- eav_obj - хранилище объектов сущностей
- eav_attr - атрибуты, глобально на всю БД с указанными типами данных и ссылкой на хранилище значений
- eav_ent_attr - набор атрибутов сущности
- ну и eav_store_val_... - соответствующие типам данных хранилища значений

Все вроде и ничего, запросы формирую на php

В БД планируется хранить величины десятичные и целые в т.ч. и величины СИ от фемто до пета значений,
долго думал как лучше, либо хранилище INT разбить на два столбца, но что-то муторно на скрипте это описывать, float и всякие double по понятным причинам отсеялись сразу. Ну в итоге ничего более гениального в голову не пришло как DECIMAL(30,15) округлить на стороне сервера или клиента не так сложно как мне кажется. Но хочу узнать насколько такая таблица может оказаться тяжелой. Дайте добрый совет горе программисту.

Заранее благодарю за ответы, сильно не поливайте! )))

Comment: *хочу узнать насколько такая таблица может оказаться тяжелой.* Да какая разница? Модель адекватна? Нормальная форма обеспечена? остальное - побоку. До оптимизации тебе ещё как пёхом до Китая...